# После выключения вызывает точку останова, какой-то косяк с указателями

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[image: проблема наверняка в процедуре in]

[image: После выключения выводит это]

Никак не пойму в чем проблема. Кто знает подскажите в чем и как исправить)

Comment: Код следует писать текстом

Comment: void in(double *m = new double[]){
 string name; cin >> name; 
 ifstream f(name); 
 for (int i = 0; !f.eof(); i++){
  f >> m[i]; n++; 
 }
 f.close();
}
Ошибка наверняка в этой процедуре

Comment: Но не пойму где именно

Comment: Cкорее всего это глюк дебагера. Возможно надо обновить студию. Там в самой dll скорее всего `int 3` прописано (видел фрагмент исключения). А вы покажите стакфрейм с дизассемблером ip-остановки - и увидите в чём проблема. Скорее всего там `int 3` написано

Comment: Между `ifstream` разве не нужно поставить пробел?

Comment: ifstream -- из <fstream>

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно, как у вас вообще компилируется

```
void in(double * m = new double[]) ...
```

Большое у меня подозрение, что проблема тут с выходом за границы массива...

И еще - у вас в цикле проверка `!f.eof()` сработает не так, как вам нужно - только после того, как будет сделано чтение за концом файла, так что одно чтение у вас будет лишним.